# Descargar con wget una carpeta de un ftp que se accede por la web que contiene subcarpetas

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Estoy tratando de descargar con wget unas subcarpetas que contienen varios archivos y solo me descarga un index.html,
dejo lo que estoy haciendo, 
explicación:

> servidor de descarga   http://seguridad.es/descargas/actualizaciones/

dentro de actualizaciones hay 2 carpetas y un archivo que los nombres cambian  diario y dentro de las carpetas hay varios archivos y me hace falta descargar todo ese contenido y gaurdarlo en la carpeta **actualizacion**.

Esto es lo que he hecho

> wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=proxy.es -l3 -np http://seguridad.es/descargas/actualizaciones/ -P /var/www/html/seguridad/actualizacion/

Y como puedo descargar de varios ficheros que tienen la misma fecha pero no la hora ejemplo 201810121030.zip y 201810121200.zip el mas actualizado que seria 201810121200.zip

Comment: Que nombre tienen las carpetas que se encuentran alli adentro?

Comment: son archivos .zip que varia el nombre diario porque tienen la fecha

Answer (score -2):

```
wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=proxy.es -r -nd -A zip http://seguridad.es/descargas/actualizaciones/ -P /var/www/html/seguridad/actualizacion/
```

Comment: esto es una respuesta?

Comment: Antonio, no pegues solo codigo. lo importante de verdad es la explicacion del mismo. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo